# Creating a Histogram

Tags: java, arrays

For an assignment, I was given horrible instructions that I cannot follow and my professor is slow with emails so I think I'll get a better response here.

Initially the goal is to convert the normal colours, RGB, to chromaticity using the formula `{r,g} = {R,G}/(R+G+B)`. Then we are to create a histogram with r and g being the axis'. The number of bins should be equal to `1 + log2(n) where n = number of rows`.

How is this even possible? Say we have an array of 4x4 that we have to create a histogram out of into a 3x3 matrix, this would not divide evenly and we would have issues...

**Here are the project specifications:**

> It turns out that we also know that if we replace the colour, RGB, by
>   the chromaticity {r, g} = {R, G}/(R + G + B) then the image is much
>   more characteristic of the surfaces being imaged, rather than of the
>   light illuminating those surfaces. So, instead of colour, {R, G, B},
>   let’s use chromaticity, {r, g}. [But watch out for black, i.e., {R, G,
>   B}={0, 0, 0}, pixels.]
>
> The nice thing about chromaticity is that it’s 2D. So our histogram is
>   a 2D array, with r along one axis and g along another. The
>   chromaticity is necessarily in the interval [0, 1]. But how many bins
>   along each axis should we use? Applying (a cheap version of) a rule of
>   thumb called Sturges’s Rule, the number of bins N = 1 + log2(n), where
>   n=size of data, so a rough idea is to use n = number of rows, so e.g.
>   N = 7 bins along each of the r and g directions. That makes our
>   histogram, H, a small, 7 × 7 array of integer values. If we normalize
>   to make the sum of H equal unity, then we have an array of floats.

I am **NOT** asking for anyone to do the work, I am simply asking for clarification if anyone knows how if this is possible.

At the moment I am able to get the chromaticity values:

```
       for(int i= 0; i < 1280; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < 720; j++) {
                rgb = resTemp.getRGB(i, j);

                R = (rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
                G = (rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
                B = (rgb) & 0xFF;

                r = R/(R+G+B);
                g = G/(R+G+B);
                b = B/(R+G+B);

            }
        }
```

Comment: This is awfully confusing. Chroma is supposed to be a wheel, not an histogram. Then the histogram becomes a 2D grid. Then you have a "size of data", which we know nothing about, define size, define data? Then from a 2D grid, we get rows and bins, like a vertical histogram? With n lowercase and N uppercase, what the... And finally a H appearing out of nowhere

Comment: Answer : Change professor.

Comment: yeah I am just completely confused on what he is trying to ask us to do.

Comment: Forget the text and try to do something like this for a starter, maybe : http://1.static.img-dpreview.com/files/p/TS940x940~forums/50817525/fbd4dc28141546248fc2f2a381077950

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a 2D chroma value in the range 0..1, 0..1

```
r = R/(R+G+B);
g = G/(R+G+B);
```

That means for each pixel you have a 2d value you could place somewhere in this continous space

```
^ R
|(1,0)
|
|(0,0)    (0,1) G
|----------->
```

If you bin that in a 2x2 way you'll assign each to a bin like

```
R
^
|-------|------|
|  bin  | bin  |
|       |      |
|-------|------|
|  bin  | bin  |
|       |      |
|-------|------|>G
```

E.g. a value of [0.3, 0.2] goes into the bottom left. [0.9, 0.9] into the top right. You can make that into a finer 7x7 grid as well.

Now you iterate over all the [r,g] values and count how many values go into which bin. Result is maybe something like

```
  30  |  12
 ------------
  4   |  12
```

This is histogram H.

Now you can normalize it by converting values to percentage. That's done by dividing by the total. E.g. `30 / (30+12+4+12)` for the first. And the final result is an array of floats.

```
  0.5 |  0.2
 ------------
  0.0 |  0.2
```

Comment: It's not the first time you see this question, do you? So the number of bins is the 1 + log2(n) formula, it's a divider.

Comment: Thank you, this worked out perfectly. What I changed a bit was, for each `r` and `g` value, I multiplied this by the size of N which would yield me a value that fits somewhere on the histogram array.

Comment: It is the first time I see this question, I know how histograms work in general though.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: *Nobody* on this site can give you definitive instructions on how to interpret your assignment question. You'll have to ask whomever assigned this task to you.

That said, it seems to me that you're misunderstanding the concept of a histogram. The number of bins in the histogram need not divide the number of pixels in your image.

Let's make up a small example. Taking your example of a 4 × 4 pixels picture (which really is too small to be meaningful), let's say the individual pixels have the following (*r*, *g*) values (which you've computed beforehand using the given formula).

```
(0.162153, 0.888718) (0.712812, 0.531226) (0.604891, 0.348852) (0.948258, 0.439340) 
(0.109330, 0.891049) (0.600158, 0.697887) (0.420215, 0.132211) (0.187572, 0.404733) 
(0.321997, 0.372477) (0.053720, 0.134205) (0.662678, 0.775244) (0.717968, 0.761581) 
(0.185886, 0.622118) (0.527020, 0.676139) (0.612300, 0.059857) (0.507551, 0.136314)
```

Now you want to compute your 3 × 3 histogram with the *r* value along the first and the *g* value along the second axis.  Since your values are from the interval [0, 1] and you have three intervals along each axis, those intervals are [0, 1/3), [1/3, 2/3) and [2/3, 1]. (How you want to handle the rounding-up and down is up to you.) For each (*r*, *g*) pair, you have to decide into what bin it goes. So, for example, the first pair (0.162153, 0.888718) goes into bin (0, 2) because 0.162153 ∈ [0, 1/3) and 0.888718 ∈ [2/3, 1]. If you do this for each of the 16 pairs of numbers and keep record how many times you hit each bin, you should come up with the following histogram.

```
1    3    2 
3    1    3 
0    2    1
```

Comment: Thanks! This and the other answer really showed me exactly where my fault was.